# SAPUI5 filter bar search in filter group items with multi combobox

Tags: sapui5

[aFilters array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seesN.png)i tried to filter using filter bar but the value doesnt come out. there is no error, just the value doesnt come out

```
onSearch: function(oEvent) {
    //get the filter bar from the event
    var oFilterBar = oEvent.getSource();

    //get the filter items from the filter bar
    var aFilterGroupItems = oFilterBar.getFilterGroupItems();

    //map the array of FilterItems to a new array of sap.ui.model.Filter objects
    var aFilters = aFilterGroupItems.map(function(oFilterGroupItem) {

        //get the filter item name (which is now the same as the filter property name)
        var sFilterName = oFilterGroupItem.getGroupName();

        //use the filter bar to get the control for the filter
        var oControl = oFilterBar.determineControlByFilterItem(oFilterGroupItem);

        //use the control to get the selected value (selected key)
        var sSelectedValue = oControl.getSelectedKeys();                

        var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(sFilterName, "EQ", sSelectedValue);

        return oFilter;
   });

   this.getView().byId("table").getBinding("items").filter(aFilters);
}
```

---

Comment: Can you give us more information ? How does the model look like the table is bound to . Have you debbuged your code and checked that you passing not an empty aFilters array to the filter method ?

Comment: Hi, i think the problem is since i have multiple multi combobox, they just filter everything using AND, that is why nothing show up when i just filter using one combobox. so the filter operator should only works when i select the key with the value, right? do u know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In [Filter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter) documentation provided by SAP, it is mentioned that if you want to combine multiple filters (AND or OR), you should create a new Filter object with the property `filters`which contains an array of the defined Filter Objects you wish to apply.

Based on that information, you could try adding following code in your onSearch function (after closing the `.map()`):

```
var oFinalFilter = sap.ui.model.Filter({
    filters: aFilters, //aFilters = array of created Filter-objects
    and: true //true|false depending on requirements
});
```

and replace

```
this.getView().byId("table").getBinding("items").filter(aFilters);
```

by

```
this.getView().byId("table").getBinding("items").filter(oFinalFilter);
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried your solutions. now, it showing something, which is all data, but it doesnt filter. for example, when i choose to filter Created By - John from the multicombobox, it should display only the data that was created by John

Comment: could you show me what is in the array `aFilters`, then I can maybe see what is going wrong.

Comment: i include the picture at my Questions. u can click the link of [aFilters array]  at the beginning of my questions. is that the one that u want?

Comment: yes, I notice that you create a Filter for each FilterItem, even if it is not filled in? You shouldn't do that. Only create a Filter if the user has inserted something for that filteritem.

Comment: i know. do u know how to do that?

Comment: Also your `oValue1` is an array for each Filter, this should be only one value and not an array. If you want a specific column to contain multiple values, you'll have to create a Filter where the property `filters` equals the array of a Filter for each possible value. and your `and` property should be set to true

Comment: @LibraWarmheart In order to check if your Filter is empty or not, I would assume (not sure since I don't know what type of filter you have), you could try `if (control.getValue() && control.getValue() !== "")`. if it has a Value then create your filter